# Why doesn't Mido remember her father when she first saw him, despite the hypnosis process?

Tags: plot-explanation, oldboy

I just saw "Oldboy" (the Korean one) a few days ago and I really enjoyed it, but I just don't get why Mido (Oh-Dae Su's daughter) can't remember her father's face or name.

I know she has been hypnotized and everything but she still had a childhood and her life, and at the beginning of the movie Oh Dae Su wants to talk to her on the phone for her birthday, that means she can speak/understand people, so she was obviously old enough to remember her father's face and/or name... A few weeks later her mother is murdered (and Oh Dae Su is false-accused because the police can't find him). It's such a tragic and important event in a life I can't believe she forgot completely about it and the name and/or face of the one who killed her mother only because she has been hypnotized.

Plus, if Oh Dae Su doesn't know her name (Mido) that means they changed it as well --and that she completely forgot about her old name. Is it possible? So maybe Oh Dae Su can't recognize his daughter because it has been too long and because of the hypnosis, but is it logical that MIDO doesn't recognize her own father?

Comment: It is his daughter's 4th birthday, and he is imprisoned for 15 years. It is not unreasonable that someone so young would not remember the appearance of their father after a 15 year absence.

Answer (score 1):

She does remember vaguely, when she welcomes back Oh Dae-Su to the sushi restaurant and appears confused when he says it's the first time he visits the restaurant:

> You look very familiar. Have we met before?

Source:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).